# Xcode 4.5(iOS 6 SDK) won't work with old projects, freezing when compiling xib files

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgrade to Mountain Lion and XCode 4.5, then when I open the old projects that work fine with XCode 4.2(iOS SDK 5) on Snow Leopard then build, it's stuck while compiling the xib files.  the xib files are created with old SDKs(XCode 3.2.5 and XCode 4.2).
if I select a xib file, instead of showing the xib editing interface, it simply freezes XCode.

Any idea how to fix this?

also I wonder if there is a way to install XCode 4.2 on Mountain Lion? my old installation is for Snow Leopard so it won't work now, but from apple website there is just a XCode 4.2 Lion/Snow leopard to download.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have 3 versions of old XCode installed(3.2.1 3.2.5,4.2), delete it with

sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

then restart and now no freezing any more